# Scrapy / crawling - detecting spider traps or infinite websites

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Having read "[Why Johnny Can’t Pentest: An Analysis of Black-box Web Vulnerability Scanners](http://sefcom.asu.edu/publications/black-box-scanners-dimva2010.pdf)", it is understood that there are websites such as calendar applications which crawlers have difficulty in dealing with. They are seemingly "infinite" websites which can just contain links to the next day/month/year etc.

Also, some websites set up spider traps or may inadvertently create a similar system (where the page links are never-ending).

If I a) have the permission of the site owner to crawl freely through their website and b) wish to use scrapy, what sort of technique can I use to determine if I have indeed encountered an "infinite" website, not specific to any example?

Note: I'm not talking about "infinite" scrolling, but rather when there are endless pages.

An example of an infinite website could be (though pointless and trivial):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['count'])){
    $count = intval($_GET['count']);
    $previous = $count - 1;
    $next = $count + 1;
    ?>
    <a href="?count=<?php echo $previous;?>">< Previous</a>

    Current: <?php echo $count;?>

    <a href="?count=<?php echo $next;?>">Next ></a>
    <?
}

?>
```

where you just keep click next and previous to reveal more pages.

Comment: Have you considered trying to limit the search per node of your search frontier , like if you go to Google Calendar then make sure that you only search for 5 or 6 web pages before you to the next site in the frontier

Comment: How would you know you have reached such an infinite website, is there a mechanism for detecting it?

Comment: Comparing the url could be usable option , if your website uses get ,then you could compare the queries in the visited list and if there is a high similarity for a high count , maybe infinite , I can't think of a test for such sites other than a human generated list but mechanicaly comparing url similarity is the most feasible

Answer (score 1):

Even when pagination is endless, content usually is not. So, when the issue is endless pagination, you can prevent endless looping by fetching the next page only if the current page has content or, if you want to be optimum, only when the current page has the known number of items per page.

In other cases, such as browsing a calendar where some dates may have values where others do not, you can hardcode a limit on your spider (if the date covered by the next URL is X or older, do not parse further).

Answer (score -1):

One thing I can think of it that pass all items IDs to next page you are scraping
and then check if the next page has same items, that means pagination has ended, there are no new records

```
def parse(self, response):

    this_page_items = []
    for item in response.css("li .items")
        this_page_items.extend([ item.css("any unique thing here").extract_first() ])


    if "prev_page_items" in response.meta:
        prev_page_items = response.meta['prev_page_items']
        if sorted(prev_page_items) == sorted(this_page_items):
            return #ternimate next page calls

    #go to next page
    yield Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={"prev_page_items": this_page_items})
```

Comment: Seems you misunderstood, an infinite does not end and doesn't necessarily have pagination as you describe

Comment: then what does infinite means? any specific example?

Comment: @ak1652 can you share me link of the site you are crawling?

Comment: Please kindly read my question or the paper I have linked to understand what is meant by infinite. But infinite could be Google Calendar, it is an endless set of pages which can just be opened because dates are infinite